# access over different IP network over the same cable

Tags: ip, ethernet

I have two machines: A and B

A and B are in the same Ethernet network divided only be a switch but they have different IP network.

A is on 10.0.0.1/16 and B is on 172.17.1.1/24.

I have access to A but cannot change it's network settings.

How to access B from A?

I can change network settings on B but cannot access it.

Only telnet connection is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use TCP/IP to communicate between the two machines as things stand; you need a router in between. Your switch might be able to act as a router, depending on its exact make and model. If you can change network settings on B, give it a new IP address in the same subnet as A and you'll be OK.

Comment: that switch is not a router, and I cannot access B in any way. But it is on the same cable. I know only that it is there and has that IP I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

A switch doesn't perform routing, unless it's a L3 switch. So either add a router to perform routing or do the following:

1. Change the IP on machine A to an IP in the 172.17.1.0/24 subnet.
2. You'll be able to access machine B. Change the IP settings on machine B and save it.
3. At this moment you will lose connection, just change the IP settings on machine A and you'll have a working connection! ;)